# Kafkacat how to republish a binary message maintaining key

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

I have been trying to use kafkacat to find a message in a topic and publish it back into the topic. We use protobuf so the message values should be in bytes (Keys can be different such as strings or bytes). However, I am unable to publish the message that could be deserialized properly.

How can I do this with kafkacat? I am also open to using other recommended tools for doing this.

---

Example attempt:

```
kafkacat -b <broker> -t <topic> -o -10 -e -c 1 -C -K: > test2.txt
```

```
cat test2.txt | kafkacat -b <broker> -t <topic> -P -K:
```

test2.txt shows:

```
21aa7e2f-41a1-4972-9108-3057627d53f0:
Y/<protobuf.class.path>i
$21aa7e2f-41a1-4972-9108-3057627d53f0A
DIABETEBG_METERBG300"BG300*QP3687WK02000012????
```

But when I use the same kafkacat consumer command to get the result, I just get the last line:

```
DIABETEBG_METERBG300"BG300*QP3687WK02000012????
```

---

I think the problem is that the consuming outputs lines (might be a part of the payload?) And the producer is treating each line as a new message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the producer is treating each line as a new message

That's correct.

If you have a binary file, I suggest writing code for this, as kafkacat assumes UTF8 encoded strings as input

Comment: I'm hoping for some standard tooling that does this, as I think this is a pretty common use case.
Also, I would like a tool like kafka-console-consumer/producer or kafkacat with all of its options available. like selecting a particular partition/offset, or searching by timestamp, etc..

Comment: I ended up writing a script.

Comment: Sending whole files as a Kafka message is not a common use case

Comment: Agreed, but simply sending messages from one kafka topic to another is though.
I ended up writing a script in scala using apache kafka libraries (and cakesolutions) that just used Bytes (de)serialization). 
I added as input a list of headers of the original message to keep (which was needed for our use case)

Comment: From one topic to another, built in tool would be MirrorMaker